# Input....and every element must be continuous Error using sklearn MultinominalHMM

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Trying to create a left right discrete HMM in sklearn to recognize words from recognized characters.  symbol set is all " " + 26 letters  for 27 total symbols.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import hmm

# alphabet is symbols
symbols = [' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',  #0-10
           'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',  #11-20
           'u','v','w','x','y','z']                  #21-26
num_symbols = len(symbols)

# words up to 6 letters
n_states = 6   

obsONE = np.array([ [0,0,15,14,5,0],     # __one_
                [15,14,5,0,0,0],     # one___
                [0,0,0,15,14,5],     # ___one
                [0,15,14,5,0,0],     # _one__
                [0,0,16,14,5,0],     # __pne_
                [15,14,3,0,0,0],     # onc___
                [0,0,0,15,13,5],     # ___ome
                [0,15,14,5,0,0],     # _one__
                [0,0,15,14,5,0],     # __one_
                [15,14,5,0,10,15],   # one_jo
                [1,14,0,15,14,5],     # an_one
                [0,15,14,5,0,16],     # _one_p
                [20,0,15,14,5,0],     # t_one_
                [15,14,5,0,10,15],     # one_jo
                [21,20,0,15,14,5],     # ut_one
                [0,15,14,5,0,20],     # _one_t
                [21,0,15,14,5,0],     # u_one_
                [15,14,5,0,10,15],     # one_jo
                [0,0,0,15,14,5],     # an_one
                [0,15,14,5,0,26],     # _one_z
                [5,20,0,15,14,5] ])    


pi = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])  # initial state is the left one always

A = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],  # node 1 goes to node 2
          [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],  # node 2 can self loop or goto 3
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0],  # node 3 can self loop or goto 4
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0],  # node 4 can self loop or goto 5
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5],  # node 5 can self loop or goto 6
          [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])  # node 6 goes to node 1     

model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=n_states,
                       startprob=pi,          # this is the start matrix, pi
                       transmat=A,            # this is the transition matrix, A
                       params='e',            # update e in during training (aka B)
                       init_params='ste')     # initialize with s,t,e   

model.n_symbols = num_symbols
model.fit(obsONE)
```

But I get ValueError: Input must be both positive integer array and every element must be continuous.

The code seems to directly want observations to be implemented as [0,1,2,3,4,5]

How should I set this up to get to the HMM model that I want???

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It seems to me that the observation sequence that is input doesn't contain some characters from the vocabulary. So instead of assigning numbers to them statically, you can assign numbers to characters after finding out what characters are present in the observation sequence.

(eg.)
Suppose
Word = 'apzaqb'

use

Symbols = ['a','b','p','q','z'] for numbering

(ie.) ObsOne = np.array([0,2,4,0,3,1])

instead of

Symbols = ['','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] for numbering

(ie.) ObsOne = np.array([1,16,26,1,17,2])